# iOS Linked-in SDK returning null AuthToken , even with successful authentication

Tags: objective-c, authentication, linkedin-api

In my iOS application, I am using v1 Linked-in SDK manager to retrieve linked-in profile information.

It was working well couple of months back, but now even with proper authentication and right set of permissions, the *createSessionWithAuth* successful call-back block getting executed but the returned authToken is null & has invalid token-expiry-date . The following code is used for authentication and AuthToken retrial

```
[LISDKSessionManager 
createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, nil]
    state:nil
    showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
    successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
        NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
        LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
    }
    errorBlock:^(LISDKAuthError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%s","error called!");
    }
];
```

I have checked with the configurations (Bundle id, client key & client secret) and those are correct. What could be the possible cause ? Is v1 not supported ? Could that be the root-cause of the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All LinkedIn SDKs have officially reached their end of life as of May 1, 2019. The LinkedIn blog https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates shows the following:

> SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0 directly from their apps.